# How to install Turbo C++ in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I tried to install turbo c++ using the methods given on this site but every time I run dos box emulator on my Ubuntu 16.04 after typing `mount c ~`
then I typed `C:` and then when I typed `cd Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0` (the file name which was in my case)  it showed error and said:

```
try Turbo (sorry space is not included b/w turbo and C)C~1
```

and again after typing `Turbo C~1` it said

```
unable to change to: Turbo (sorry space is not included b/w turbo and C)C~1
```

Please help me because I am waiting to see the blue screen of turbo C++ and my coding back!

Comment: which site is it? Try using open quote and close quote like this `"Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0"`

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to reduce confusion would be to use your file manager to rename the folder `Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0` to something with 8 or fewer characters, like `TURBO`. Then open DosBox, mount the C: drive, and you should be able to `cd` to that directory more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try using open quote and close quote like this `"Turbo C++ 3.2.2.0"`

This might be caused by spacing.